# Optimization with rank constraint

Tags: optimization, matrix-rank, regression-analysis

Following some problems I like to explore, I found myself looking at minimizing the following:
$$ \min_{B \text{ with rk}(B)<q} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-x_i^TBx_i)^2 $$
where $y_i \in \mathbb{R}, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^p-\lbrace 0 \rbrace, B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$.
Would someone have any clue what are the known solutions to these kind of problems?

Comment: Are you minimizing with respect to $B$, I assume?

Comment: @VanBaffo Yes sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Why are you taking the Frobenius norm here? Since $y\in\mathbb{R}$ shouldn't it just be the square without any norm?

Comment: Well, I thought I could translate my problem using a Frobenius norm, obviously it was a mistake... I am sorry, I edited the question if you don't mind taking a look again I would be thankful

Comment: There is no need to sum, it doesn't make sense; $y\in\mathbb{R}$ means that there is only one component.

Comment: Yes I just very badly translated my initial question cause I'm consedering several components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for rank $0$ matrices, the only answer is $B=0$.  If $x=0$ then the choice of $B$ does not matter, so we might as well take $B=0$.  If you allow rank $1$ matrices, then the answer is $B=\alpha xx^T$, where $\alpha$ is chosen from the equation $y= x^TBx = \alpha \|x\|^4$, so that $\alpha = y/\|x\|^4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is identically $0$ then you can take any matrix $B$ of rank $q-1$ - they are all optimal.

On the other hand, if $x$ is not identically $0$ then assume without loss of generality that the first component of $x$ is nonzero. Let $B = \mathrm{diag}((\alpha,1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots))$ be a diagonal matrix whose first entry is $\alpha$ and which is at most rank $q-1$, i.e., there are at least ($p-(q-1)$) entries equal to $0$.

We have
$$x^TBx = \alpha x_1^2 + x_2^2 +\ldots +x_{q-1}^2$$

Since $\alpha$ is arbitrary, you can make it as big as or as small as necessary so that $\alpha x_1^2 = y-(x_2^2+x_3^2+\ldots +x_{q-1}^2)$ and the minimum is thus $0$. This is not the only solution but it attains the minimum ($0$).

Comment: Note the $rk(B)<q$ constraint.  You have one too many entries on the diagonal.

Comment: You're right, I thought there was equality. Your answer is much more elegant in my opinion anyways!